# code-server WebSocket close with status code 1006

Tags: digital-ocean, droplet, code-server

I am trying to install code-server 3.6.2 on a cloud platform. I have tried both AWS and digitalocean machines but in both systems, I can open code server but it gives an error "WebSocket close with status code 1006".

I have followed the procedure from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-the-code-server-cloud-ide-platform-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 0):

code-server uses websocket to connect.Do you use HTTPS?
If so, you should Use wss to forward ws.like this:

```js
// forward websocket (wss -> ws)
httpsServer.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
  proxy.ws(req, socket, head, {
    target: 'ws://...',
    ws: true
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this and other errors happen when you use code server locally
To solve it you can use the --link parameter that gives you a url with temporary https, or you can also use ngrok

```
 //Option 1
    code-server --host 127.0.0.1 --bind-addr 0.0.0.0:9000 --auth password --link


 //Option 2
    code-server --host 127.0.0.1 --bind-addr 0.0.0.0:9000 --auth password 
    ngrok http 9000
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Are you using Nginx as a reverse proxy server, which code-server is the backend? If so, try nginx config as follows:

```
location ~ ${your frontend url pattern} {
  resolver {your DNS server}

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  # trick here, if absent, the server will block the websocket request! the server check if origin equal to host, shown above.
  proxy_set_header Origin http://${your backend host}/;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  # trick here, consult https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html for Nginx official doc
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding gzip;

  proxy_cookie_domain ${your backend host} ${your frontend host};

  proxy_pass ${your backend url pattern};
}
```

config above working for me. my scene：

- code-server: 4.18.0, running in an container of Kubernetes
- nginx:1.9.7, running in an container of another Kubernetes.